# Error 6 Overflow using Access 2.0 and Access Basic

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been using the same program since 1994 which I wrote from scratch to do loan servicing.  About 2 months ago we started getting an error 6 when we went to delete records.  I entered the error into the Google machine and found this site.  I also found out we have reached the limit of transaction numbers in an integer so I just tried to re-dimension a variable as long:

```
Sub DeleteTransactions_Click () 

  Dim TransID As Long                    'I just added this line   

  'On Error GoTo DeleteTransactionsError ' removed the on error so I could see    
  TransID = TransactionID                'added this    
  GlobalTransactionID = TransID         'modified from TransactionID to TransID
  If MsgBox("Have the Transactions been Printed?", 4 + 48, "Confirm Printing") <> 6 Then Exit Sub   
  If MsgBox("Delete Transactions for Contract ID " & GlobalContractID & " ?", 4 + 48, "Confirm Contract") <> 6 Then Exit Sub
  If MsgBox("Delete Transactions Starting with Transaction ID " & GlobalTransactionID & " ?", 4 + 48, "Confirm Transactions") <> 6 Then Exit Sub    
  DoCmd Hourglass True
```

I am still getting the error 6 stack overflow.  Does anyone have an idea on how to get this to work? Many thanks!

Comment: VB.NET was not around in 1994 so the correct tag to use would be the VB6 one.  Also, please read [Ask], take the [tour] and format the code.

Comment: What line does the error occur?

Comment: What is the definition of 'GlobalTransactionID' - integer or long (it needs to be long)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code it's impossible to tell but you probably need to change TransactionID and/or GlobalTransactionID to Long as well. That's also assuming the table in the db has been changed to handle it if required.

Comment: Thank you @MWS.  TransactionID is the Counter for a table in my Access 2.0 database.  If I remember correctly, I set GlobalTransactionID so I could share it with the other buttons on the form such as Print Transactions.  Here is the SQL statement regarding the record I am working on:

Comment: Fixed problem by dim GlobalTransactionID as long.